# Can I use JQuery dropdown AND suckerfish for the same menu?

Tags: jquery, css

I am using a JQuery "accordion" style dropdown menu. However, when JS is disabled, my menu is a giant list of items. Is it possible to use a suckfish style menu if js is turned off, but use my JQuery menu if it's enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be difficult, and get a bit ugly.  I'm sure it can be done though.

Have you considered something like [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/)?  It would give users a more consistent interface whether or not JS is enabled.

Comment: I'm trying to implement an accordion menu, more like this: http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/jquery-accordion-menu-redux/ 
I just wanted it to degrade nicely - there are a lot of menu items and if JS is disabled, I don't want the user presented with a million options. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if you could pull off a menu like that without JS. I'm still thinking you should present a more consistent interface, but maybe you could take the suckerfish menu and re-class it in script to turn it into the accordion?  That approach will probably be your best bet.